# Determine all p $\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following integral converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The integral is: 
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(\cos(x) - 1)x^2}{x^p + (x + 1)^6} dx$$

Now, what I did was this:

$$\frac{(\cos(x) - 1)x^2}{x^p + (x + 1)^6} \leq \frac{\cos(x)x^2}{x^p + (x + 1)^6} \leq \frac{\cos(x)x^2}{x^p + x^6} \leq \frac{x^2}{x^p + x^6} \leq \frac{x^2}{x^p}$$

And $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^p} dx$ converges when $p > 3$ because it is a $p$-integral. Is this approach right?

**Edit**: I only have to know what to do with $\int_0^1$

Comment: The left hand side of your inequality is non-positive and the right hand side is non-negative, so the convergence of the integral of one side has little to do with the convergence of the integral of the other.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^\infty x^{-p}\ dx$ never converges. It's either $\int_a^\infty$ or $\int_0^a$

Comment: For $p \ge 6$ the integrand is dominated by a constant times $x^{2-p}$, but for $p < 6$ it is dominated by a constant times $x^{2-6}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$ \left|\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\ dx\right| \le \int_0^{\infty} |f(x)|\ dx $$

and $|\cos x-1| = 1-\cos x$, we consider
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-\cos x)x^2}{x^p + (x+1)^6}\ dx \le \int_0^\infty \frac{2x^2}{x^p + (1+x)^6}\ dx \le \int_0^1 2x^2 + \int_1^\infty \frac{2x^2}{x^p + x^6} $$

The first term clearly converges, so let's look at the other one

If $p > 6$
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{2x^2}{x^p+x^6} \le \int_1^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^p}\ dx $$
which always converges

If $p \le 6$
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{2x^2}{x^p+x^6} \le \int_1^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^6}\ dx $$
which always converges

So the integral converges for $\forall p$